# Who said 'He's Dead' or 'She's Dead' the most other than McCoy

Tags: star-trek

One of the biggest tropes from *Star Trek* is McCoy's line 'He's Dead Jim' for basically every redshirt other than Scotty.  I was watching *VOY* 'Mortal Coil' today and noticed Paris said 'He's Dead'.  That got me wondering: **after McCoy, who says the phrase "He's dead" or "She's dead" the most?**

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_W3hZ1S6TI

Comment: Before you down vote on the grounds of a self Q and A, be aware that I started researching an answer after posting the question

Comment: @OftenRight I'm tempted to downvote on the grounds of "who the hell cares?" :-))) (I haven't downvoted though.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor well, considering it's such a huge trope I think it's interesting to see whether it is justified; essentially I'm considering how common it is amongst other characters.  Perhaps I'm the only one who cares!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking through [all the instances in all episodes and movies](http://scriptsearch.dxdy.name/?page=results&query=(%7Bline%7CHe%27s%20dead,She%27s%20dead,%7D)), I can conclude that the winner is...

## Kirk: 5 times

- Conscience of the King (x2)
- Operation: Annihilate!
- The Changeling
- I, Mudd

---

And for the record, McCoy only says the phrase 'He's Dead' or 'She's Dead' 12 times ([source](http://scriptsearch.dxdy.name/?page=results&query=(%7Bspeaker%7CMcCoy,%7D)%20and%20(%7Bline%7CHe%27s%20dead,%7D)))

Comment: still more often than Kirk said "Beam me up, Scotty." :-)